# Primefaces - Do not display message for required fields, just hightlight border

Tags: java, forms, validation, jsf, primefaces

I have a Primefaces 3-field form and a `<p:messages>` tag to show some server-side validation messages. But I don't want to display the client-side messages related to the `required="true"` option, just highlight the input field with red.

Is there a way to do it with Primefaces?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set `<p:messages globalOnly="true"/>`, this will just show global messages, which are not attached to any particular field. Also you can user Primefaces' `<p:outputLabel/>` for label of input elements, it will add error css to input elements.

You should also update form when you do submit. For example if you do that with command button add `update="form_id"`

Comment: I set the globalOnly option but no luck. The messages are not displayed but the CSS is also not rendered. Also, the `<p:outputLabel/>` doesn't work with `<p:password/>` (it's a Primefaces limitation).

Comment: You should also update form when you do submit. For example if you do that with command button add `update="form_id"`

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this --> **rendered="#{not facesContext.validationFailed}"**

```
 <p:messages
    rendered="#{not facesContext.validationFailed}"
    id="msg"
    showDetail="true"
    autoUpdate="false"
    closable="true" />
```